# Assignment of an ivar not working

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios

I'm seeing a bizarre case where simple assignment to an instance variable is not working.  The right hand object is non-nil, but refuses to be assigned to an instance variable (with the same type).  This is not happening consistently within the app.

I have a class like this:

```
@interface FooViewController : UIViewController {
  UIView *contentView;
  BOOL testBool;
}
@end
@implementation FooViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  UIView *theContentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];

  // this assignment fails for some reason:
  contentView = [theContentView retain];
  /* at this point, contentView == nil */

  UIView *bar = theContentView; // this works
  testBool = YES; // this works
}
@end
```

and a subclass like this:

```
@interface BarViewController : FooViewController {
}
@end
```

When I instantiate the BarViewController from a nib, when the execution gets to the viewDidLoad defined in the superclass, the strange behavior above happens.  Instance variables "refuse to assign".

However, if I add a dummy instance variable to the subclass, the expected behavior returns.  Instance variables correctly assign in the viewDidLoad.

I'm seeing this at runtime in iOS 4.3 in the simulator using Xcode 4.0.2.  This happens both in LLVM+GCC and GCC.

This is not happening in isolation.  When I try this in a test project, it performs normally.

Comment: why not just do `contentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[self view] bounds]];`?

Comment: Are you certain viewDidLoad is being called?  Have you stepped over the assignment in the debugger to view the values of theContentView and contentView?

Comment: @dave yes, i could do that, but the underlying problem is still there. I'm simplifying the code in this example. Even adding an ivar specifically for debugging this and assigning it does not work. It's like ivars are simply not taking assignments.

Comment: What I'm seeing as of a very long process of elimination is that I'm using a subclass of this MyViewController. If that sub-class doesn't have any ivars defined, we see this issue above. If it has 1 dummy ivar, the issue goes away.

Comment: OK so I have new information -- still strange -- but I will be editing the issue shortly to explain.  I see what's going on - just not sure why.

Comment: Are you seeing this problem only when stepping through with the debugger or also when actually using the class? Sometimes the debugger in XCode 4 doesn't step properly or highlights the wrong line.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, but I don't believe you.

My first question is how you determine that `contentView` is equal to nil? Do you have a breakpoint ***after*** the assignment? If you break on the line of the assignment, that line will not yet have been executed, so `contentView` will be nil at that point.

If you're testing `contentView` in some other method it might just be that `viewDidLoad` has not been run yet.

Show me the output of:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  UIView *theContentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];

  // this assignment fails for some reason:
  contentView = [theContentView retain];
  /* at this point, contentView == nil */

  NSLog(@"theContentView: %p", theContentView);
  NSLog(@"contentView:    %p", contentView);

  UIView *bar = theContentView; // this works
  testBool = YES; // this works
}
```

If they differ I'll start believing you. (Well, maybe not, I'll still consider the possibility that you're lying.)

Comment: I'm posting this question for the very reason that it is strange. Of course I've set a breakpoint after the assignment and checked that it's actually calling viewDidLoad.  Otherwise, how would I know that these values such as testBool and bar are getting assigned properly?  I'm looking for a much deeper answer as to why this code above works in a fresh project, but doesn't for whatever reason work in my project.

Comment: @Jess, I believe you can agree that your problem is so unbelievable that it's more believable that you've misunderstood the situation.

Comment: @Jess, By the way, I'd still like to see the output of the above NSLogs, just to make sure that it's not just a debugger problem and the code actually runs fine.

Comment: Probably a debugger problem: The output of the NSLog doesn't match what I'm seeing in the debugger at all. The value for contentView is still 0x0 (nil), yet logs say different: theContentView: 0x5e02940, contentView:    0x5e02940.

Comment: @Jess, Well that's what I thought. Just to be sure, are you breaking after the logs have been printed?